# Firebase download onProgressListener not getting called often

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

In my android app I have a function to download files from my firebase storage, and when I am downloading I display a progress bar that gets updated using the downloader "onProgressListener" function, only problem is that it gets called very rarely, meaning that the downloads will go something like 0%->43%->89%->100%. Now I am not talking about small files which would make sense, I mean files that can take 5 minutes to donwload. Any idea how I can make the progress go smoother instead of just jumping?

Comment: If I recall correctly, for uploads the progress callback should fire every 256kb. Is that not what you see for downloads?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It used to be that the internal buffer size would grow over time, as the connection was seen to be stable.  Did that change?

Comment: I doubt anything changed there. But I also never knew that the notification interval could change, so in this case you might know better than I do. This SDK is nowadays open-source though, so it might be checking

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you have any idea if there is a way to make the progress get called more often? e.g every 100kb?